# Android calendar app and back button

Tags: android, calendar, save, back-button

I am opening an Android calendar from my application in order to create event. For that I use next fragment of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
...
startActivity(intent);
```

When calendar is opened and I press back button, event is saved - which I don't want to happen. If I understand correctly (from [this link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11565)) it is default behavior of calendar application. Is there anyway I can override that or I have to implement my own "calendar create event" activity?

I hope I can override it somehow. But I doubt I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can override another applications behavior. You will most likely have to create your own activity screen that captures the event information and then add or edit that calendar event to the phone programatically.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've figured out too. Thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue here, but my solution is to tell the user about this 'bug'